# Assigning python dictionary literals: are the semantics guaranteed?

Tags: python, dictionary

Simple question:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 9 2016, 06:11:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {'foo':1,'foo':2}
>>> print d
{'foo': 2}
>>> d = {'foo':2,'foo':1}
>>> print d
{'foo': 1}
```

So it seems that if I assign a dictionary literal with a duplicate key to a variable it is the second key/pair that is used, at least for this particular python version.

Is this behaviour guaranteed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [*Dictionary displays* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, **they are evaluated from left to right** to define the entries of the dictionary: each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the corresponding datum. **This means that you can specify the same key multiple times in the key/datum list, and the final dictionary’s value for that key will be the last one given.**

(Bold emphasis mine).

So yes, that is guaranteed. All Python implementations must adhere to this, deviation from the above specification would be a bug.

Older Python version documentation have not always included that last sentence, but the order of evaluation has always been explicit.

Comment: The text for Python 2.6 (which the OP uses) is a bit different: https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays

Comment: @StefanPochmann: the behaviour in 2 is no different, although there was a bug where the value expression was evaluated before the key expression.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: [Will a Python dict literal be evaluated in the order it is written?](//stackoverflow.com/q/28156687)